# Is it sensible to use symfony as native app api?

Tags: reactjs, database, api, symfony, data-synchronization

Good day,

I have a question for the experienced developers:

At the moment I work a lot with the PHP framework Symfony.

Out of interest, I would now like to delve into the topic of native app development
using React.
As part of a practice project, I want to transfer/sync data between a SQL DB on a server and the app.
My question is, is it a good way to write a symfony application for this,
which only acts as an API for the database?

- Does this make sense from a performance and effort point of view?
- What alternative ways are there?
- Which ways of storing data on servers are used most frequently in the productive environment?

I am happy about suggestions, links and informations in every direction.

Thanks and Greetings

Comment: It is very common to use symfony for your backend with a rest api. Nowadays new symfony projects are often Vue + Symfony or React + Symfony. You could also look into api platform which would help making your api.

Answer (score 0):

My answers (based on my experiences and my collegues answers) :

- As you can see on the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/26-api.html) it's very easy to made your own api with Symfony tkants to API Platform. For the performance it's very acceptable especially if you use Symfony (>= 5.4) because a lot of cleaning has been done in the kernel and PHP 8 for its performance improvements especially at compile time (JIT compiletor). More info [here](https://developers.ibexa.co/blog/benchmarks-php-7.4-8.0-jit-opcache-preloading-symfony) if you need it.
- Alternatively you can create your API rest with NodeJS but it doesn't bring much especially if your application is already made in PHP. Adding a layer can sometimes make things heavier instead of lighter.
- It's depend of your need, the size, the number of users ... You have to determine the target to choose the better solution. If you have it already I can help you.